# alsa on embedded system CORE9G25

Tags: audio, arm, embedded-linux, alsa, atmel

I have a CORE9G25-CON (256MBRAM)  (http://armdevs.com/core9g25.html) device with embedded linux installed on it.
The version of linux is:

```
# uname -or
3.6.9 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2012.11.1-dirty
ID=buildroot
VERSION_ID=2012.11.1
PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2012.11.1
```

The device is equipped with USB host connector in which I connected an USB-AUDIO interface

The USB interface is recognize by the system

```
# cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                     C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-at91-1, full speed

# cat /proc/asound/devices
      0: [ 0]   : control
     16: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
     24: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
     33:        : timer

# ls /dev/snd
controlC0  pcmC0D0c   pcmC0D0p   timer
```

I would like to handle the AUDIO interface by using ALSA but this is the error shown on the console by using the simple command aplay -l

```
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib control.c:739:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
aplay: device_list:226: control open (0): No such file or directory
aplay: conf.c:3095: snd_config_update_free: Assertion `update->count > 0 && update->finfo' failed.
Aborted
```

I googled for about a week trying to fix the problem but, up to now, i  didn't find any solution.

Could you help me to fix the problem ?
Had you other similar experience about it ?

Thank you very much for your help and cooperation

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your alsa.conf look like ?  do this

```
locate alsa.conf
```

typically found at

```
/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

do a google on

```
audio sound alsa Invalid CTL hw:0
```

this might get you on the right path

```
#alsa.conf minimal configuration
ctl.hw {
   @args [ CARD ]
   @args.CARD {
       type string
   }
   type hw
   card $CARD #with 0 alsamixer work, with $CARD alsamixer lend to invalid argument
}
```

Comment: alsa.conf file is located at /usr/share/alsa directory. The alsa.conf file was generated by the toolchain.

Comment: I used strace to trace the 'aplay .l' process and I noticed that alsa.conf file is not read. aplay -l process tries to open /usr/share/alsa (that is a directory) as alsa.conf file and, of course, I think that it doesn't rigth. How to fix it ?